# Dynamic table name vs array column in static table

Tags: arrays, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I'm using PostgreSQL to coordinate a large scale simulation which involves initializing various components of my application via arrays of integers. In particular, I have the notion of a "Controller", where each controller requires a variable number of parameters to be initialized.

I have a `job` table which stores the `controller_id` and a `controller_parameters` foreign key for actually linking to the set of parameters we want. My idea to start with was to do the following:

1. Use the `controller_id` to dynamically choose a table name from which to select the initialization parameters. Each of these tables would have a `controller_parameters` column that links the actual initialization data to the source table.
2. Once we know the table, run a `SELECT * FROM @someController_parameters_table p WHERE p.controller_parameters = controller_parameters LIMIT 1;`
3. Put these into a custom type which has an integer array field to be returned to the client.

The main problem is that this has Dynamic SQL, which I hear is not a good thing to do.

My proposed change is to have a new table, let's say `controller_parameters` which has the columns `(controller_id, parameters_id, parameters[])`. The third column stores the initialization parameters for an individual controller and parameter set.

Pros of this design are that we move back into static SQL land, which is good. Cons are that, when I generate the actual parameters to insert to the individual parameters table, I usually use a cross join to get all of the permutations of the individual parameters, and insert them accordingly to individual tables. I personally don't know how to take a cross-joined table row and convert it to an `int[]`, so that's a potential roadblock.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_agg` to take the result of a group and turn it into an array.

```
select controller_id, parameters_id, array_agg(parameter) 
from ... 
group by controller_id, parameters_id
```

Here's postgresql docs on aggregate functions:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: So array_agg() is like array() but you don't have to specify the columns? It just does every column that's not in the Group By clause? Is the order the same as what's in the Order By clause?